# restore a cassandra cluster from snapshot failed

Tags: cluster-computing, restore, cassandra-2.0

Hope someone can help. We are having issues restoring all nodes of a cassandra 2.0 cluster from a snapshot.  I have reviewed the instructions [Restoring from a snapshot][1]

Specific steps done include:

1. All data had been flushed from the memtables.
2. All nodes were compacted down to 1 sstable
3. Snapshots were taken on all nodes and saved off elsewhere
4. New cluster stood up, install from sratch of identical cluster (less data)
5. keyspace and column families were created
6. All nodes were stopped
7. commitlogs were cleared on all nodes and verified no sstable files existed
8. snapshot sstables were copied to each corresponding node under the base table folder
9. All nodes were restarted
10. Nodetool repair was run on all nodes

Result of these steps that appear to match the documentation is:

- For a 2 node cluster, nodetool cfstats on each node seems to report approximate number of keys each node would have.  nodetool status shows correct division of data by host
- logging into cqlsh and doing a select count(*) on one of the columnfamily with limit high enough to return all rows does not report back the correct/original number of rows.  It appears to report just the results of one node.

Is there a step missing from the documentation?  Why doesn't a select count(*) show all the rows?

Thanks,
dfgriffith